# How using jQuery to change a background image url with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add one background url image to my css with jQuery.
But nothing i've tried works.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('form button.btn')
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  $(".img").css("background", "url('/images/Codax.jpg')");
})
```

```css
div.img {
  height: 450px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 1px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 1px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  box-shadow: 7px 1px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  background: url('');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="perfil-img">
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>
<form>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Follow:
In the link is the directories used in the project.
[Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nVl4.png)

This Html is called from a FetchContent. The desire is to add the image in html that FetchContent calls.

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#" a-view="infoPessoal" onclick="fetchContent(this)" a-folder="administrativo">
    <i class="fas fa-user-tag"></i>
    <!-- Icones -->
    Pesssoal
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Check if your image file path is correct [see examples](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: The information that the html that owns the button and I want to add the image comes from a call FetchContent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `../images/Codax.jpg` the file path of the image should be relative to the location of the css file. You need to go up 1 dir by using  `../`.

```
 $(".img").css("background", "url('../images/Codax.jpg')")
```

Comment: images folder in the root is more likely than in a sub folder of just the current page

Comment: You switched to background-image? And what OS are you running? @freedomn-m If in project root yes, but any file path starting with just `/` refers to system root on any unix based OS.

Comment: @PatMan10 Using Windows. I edited the post with the folder directory.

Comment: You need to use `../` and not `./`. The image file path should be relative to the location of the css file not index.html. fixed my answer to show this.

Comment: Why this? Continue do not working... Maybe descontinue that.

Comment: @PatMan10 no, it's a client-side url, so it will be the web root, not the system root.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of separation of concerns, i'll recommend you to create a CSS class with the corresponding background image set, then toggle the class using the  .toggleClass() Method
i.e 
CSS should look like :

```
.background{
background : url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
width : 100%
/*Whatever other parameter*/
}
```

Js :

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $(".img").toggleClass( "background" );
});
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-image` in this line instead of just `background`

```
 $(".img").css("background-image", "url('/images/Codax.jpg')");
```